# set ATS keys in watchkit extension & watch app .plist file

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode7, watchapp

I am submitting a build in app store using xcode 7..my app also supports watch app , i am not able to figure out that do I need to set ATS(App transport security) exemption Keys in watchkit extension & watch app .plist files as well ( I am setting ATS exemption Keys in my main app .plist file)..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATS keys need to be set in iPhone App .plist file & watchkit extension .plist file (for watchOS2 support)...

Comment: I have just upgraded to ios 10 beta 3, and needed to add exemptions in this plist.  They work for the phone, not for the watch, still getting TLS connection exceptions

Comment: see my edit..u need to add exemptions in watchkit extension.plist along with iphone app.plist file..